# select a varias tablas en mysql

Tags: mysql

Buenas, necesito hacer la siguiente consulta:

Tengo 4 tablas, la primera es la principal, en la cual con el `id` es foránea en las otras 3 tablas. Necesito obtener la fecha y descripción de cada una de las tablas donde este presente el `id_tabla1`, en algunas puede tener mas registros que en las otras, ese es mis problema

¿Es posible relacionar estas tablas?

Tabla 1 principal

- id_tabla1
- Nombre

Tabla 2

- id_tabla2
- Fecha
- Descripcion
- fk_tabla1

Tabla 3

- id_tabla3
- Fecha
- Descripcion
- fk_tabla1

Tabla 4

- id_tabla4
- Fecha
- Descripcion
- fk_tabla1

quiero obtener algo mas o menos asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué deseas obtener con la consulta? Por favor edita tu pregunta. Además, si es posible, [genera un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `en algunas puede tener mas registros que en las otras, ese es mis problema`, bueno, cuál es el resultado que quieres en ese caso?, puedes explicar cuál sería la lógica acá?

Comment: ¿Nos podrías compartir el avance que tengas hasta el momento? Entiendo tu pregunta y entiendo lo que deseas, y ya con la muestra del avance que tengas podremos orientarte de una mejor manera a que encuentres la solución deseada

Answer (score 2):

> Necesito obtener la fecha y descripción de cada una de las tablas donde este presente el id_tabla1, en algunas puede tener mas registros que en las otras, ese es mis problema

Podrías usar [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html), así por ejemplo:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT 'tabla2' as tabla, fk_tabla1, fecha, descripcion FROM tabla2
  UNION SELECT 'tabla3', fk_tabla1, fecha, descripcion FROM tabla3
  UNION SELECT 'tabla4', fk_tabla1, fecha, descripcion FROM tabla4
) A
WHERE fk_tabla1 = 1
```

El resultado sería el siguiente:

```
tabla    fk_tabla1   fecha        descripcion 
tabla2   1           2016-12-29   prueba
tabla2   1           2016-12-30   prueba2
tabla3   1           2016-12-29   prueba
tabla4   1           2016-12-29   prueba
```

Answer (score 2):

Primero necesitas obtener una tabla con todas las posibles combinaciones de id y fecha que puedan ocurrir y luego utilizas ese resultado para extraer los datos de tabla2, tabla3 y tabla 4, asi:

```
SELECT tabla1_fecha.idtabla1, tabla2.fecha, tabla2.descripcion, tabla3.fecha, tabla3.descripcion, tabla4.fecha, tabla4.descripcion 
FROM 
(
    SELECT tabla1.idtabla1, fechas.fecha
    FROM tabla1 
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT fecha FROM tabla2
        UNION
        SELECT fecha FROM tabla3
        UNION
        SELECT fecha FROM tabla4    
    ) fechas
) tabla1_fecha 
LEFT JOIN tabla2 ON tabla1_fecha.idtabla1 = tabla2.fk_tabla1 AND tabla1_fecha.fecha = tabla2.fecha
LEFT JOIN tabla3 ON tabla1_fecha.idtabla1 = tabla3.fk_tabla1 AND tabla1_fecha.fecha = tabla3.fecha
LEFT JOIN tabla4 ON tabla1_fecha.idtabla1 = tabla4.fk_tabla1 AND tabla1_fecha.fecha = tabla4.fecha;
```

En MySQL obtengo el siguiente resultado:

```
idtabla1    fecha         descripcion   fecha           descripcion fecha       descripcion
1           2016-12-29    prueba          2016-12-29    prueba      2016-12-29  prueba
1           2016-12-30    prueba2
```

Comment: gracias por responder el resultado que muestras es justo lo que deseo, pero no logro entender muy bien el ejemplo.. justo en la parte de:  tabla1_fecha.idtabla1 y en fechas.fecha

Comment: Lo que se realizó fue hacer una sub-consulta para extraer todas las posibles combinaciones de id y fechas que puedan tener las tablas. Luego a esta sub-consulta se le puso el nombre de tabla1_fecha que tiene dos columnas idtabla1 (tabla1.idtabla1) y fecha (fechas.fecha). "fechas" también es el nombre de otra sub-consulta.

Comment: ya logro entender la query y probarla y si mo muestra los datos que deseo sin duplicarlos, pero antes me muestran valores nulos en todas las tablas?

Answer (score 2):

1. Con **left outer join** usando la tabla1 como principal y obteniendo los valores de la tabla2, tabla3 y tabla4 si existe el registro que coinciden con el id de la tabla1

   ```
   SELECT t1.id_tabla1, t2.fecha, t2.descripcion, 
                    t3.fecha, t3.descripcion,
                    t4.fecha, t4.descripcion 
      from 
         (  SELECT tabla1.id_tabla1, fechas.fecha
            FROM tabla1 
            INNER JOIN (
               SELECT fecha FROM tabla2 UNION
               SELECT fecha FROM tabla3 UNION
               SELECT fecha FROM tabla4 ) fechas
          ) t1 
       left join tabla2 as t2
            on t1.id_tabla1 = t2.fk_tabla1 and t1.fecha = t2.fecha
       left join tabla3 as t3
            on t1.id_tabla1 = t3.fk_tabla1 and t1.fecha = t3.fecha
       left join tabla4 as t4
            on t1.id_tabla1 = t4.fk_tabla1 and t1.fecha = t4.fecha
      wHERE t1.id_tabla1 = 1
   ```

Comment: la tabla1 no tiene clave foranea

Comment: Si tenes razón,    where t1.id_tabla1 = 1  o bien sin la condicion where, para que recorra toda la tabla1

Comment: Justo corregí esa parte.. Aun así no funciona en la tercer tabla que sólo tiene un registro.. Lo repite varias veces

Comment: Efectivamente, no tenia las tablas para hacer la prueba. Cree las tablas con los datos. Y me di cuenta de los que me decis, asi que hice una correccion utilizando una porcion del codigo de Weimar Yamit Moreno Perez

Comment: gracias acavo de probarlo y efectivamente ya no ahi duplicidad en los datos pero em todas las tablas tengo valores null antes de los datos, en que me eh equivocado?

Answer (score 1):

Si se pueden relacionar tus tablas, una vez creadas puedes usar esto para obtener lo que buscas:

```
SELECT t1.id_tabla1, t2.fecha,t2.descripcion, t3.fecha,t3.descripcion,t4.fecha,t4.descripcion
FROM tabla1 t1 
INNER JOIN tabla2 t2 ON t2.fk_tabla1 = t1.id_tabla1
INNER JOIN tabla3 t3 ON t3.fk_tabla1 = t1.id_tabla1
INNER JOIN tabla4 t4 ON t4.fk_tabla1 = t1.id_tabla1
```